Kdenlive, не сохраняет проект
Работает стабильно, проект в видео собирает, но вот когда пытаюсь просто сохранить проект, kdenlive зависает. Свернуть развернуть можно программу, но закрыть через крестик не удается, и вобще не откликается не на какие нажатия внутри интерфейса.
ОС Linux Mint 21.2 Victoria

Больше интересна не версия ОС, а самого kdenlive...

kdenlive 24.08.1
